# deforming meshes, clipping unseen geometry, creating faces

Tags: mesh

[image: examples]

1, is there any way to grab a vertex/edge/face, and pull them to warp a mesh like in #1?

2, i think read somewhere, that blender knows if an object is completely connected with no gaps in the faces (like a sphere),  and that if any other mesh clips within it, theres an option to delete all the vertices/edges/faces that cannot be seen. i cannot find this information again so maybe im wrong but if you can do that, how?

3, one thing that might be useful for me, for building complex geometry, is generating circles, selecting the edges, and using 'f' to generate faces, but doing it one at a time would be agony. if i select all the circles and press 'f', it just makes one face within each circle. is there any way to select multiple edges/vertices of 2 or more circles and get blender to make faces between them, or do i have to do it one face at a time?

Comment: Do a web search for the following tools: [**bridge edge loops**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops) and [**grid fill**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#modeling-meshes-editing-grid-fill)

Comment: As for 1, search for [propoertional edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html). For 2, [boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) might be of help.

Comment: @blendern00b please take the time to write an answer to your own question. It might help other users.